# Google Sheets update current cell using current cell data plus another cell

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I need to update a cell by using the same cell plus another one. For example, C1(updated) = C1(old value) + C2.
I have taken a few coding classes for java and C# and it would be a relatively simple problem to fix, but I've never learned basic excel or google sheets skills so I am unsure what I should do to get desired results or how to word it to find the answer in google. I tried save the cell data to another one and then using that cell for the calculation, but if the original cell changes then everything changes.

Thank you.

Comment: Please show some code.

Answer (score 0):

try :

```
var tmpData = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange('C1').getValue();
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange('C1').setValue(tmpData + SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange('C2').getValue());
```